# Hibernate generator class usage

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm refactoring an old web application (2006) using, Struts 1, hibernate 3, spring 1...

I'm upgrading libraries.

Using hibernate mapping xml file I modify "ID" / Primary key" behavior in order to be compatible with any actual database.

I was said to use :

```
<class name="com....Declaration" table="DECLARATION">
        <id name="pk" type="integer" column="PK_DECLARATION" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="native"/>
            ....
```

Now I'm using SQL Server. But if one day I must change for example to Oracle, will I have to change all my mapping in order to be compatible ?

The question is to set mapping compatible with multiple databases, the best way is to use "Native" generator or create my own ?

Comment: The references says: "It picks identity,sequence,or hilo,depending on the database." So it depends if it's valid for you.

Comment: If my 1st DB is SQL Server (identity) and if I'm required to use Oracle, do I have to change all mapping in order to set sequence  name, and create sequence on each table of the database ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. In the database you will have to do whatever it requires, and you will have to change the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. So my choice will be setting my own ID / PK generator class in order to avoid changing my mapping if I change database.

```
<class name="com...declaration.Declaration" table="DECLARATION">
        <id name="pk" type="integer" column="PK_DECLARATION" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="com....PkGenerator">
                <param name="table">SEQUENCE</param>
                <param name="primary_key_column">ENTITE</param>
                <param name="primary_key_value">DECLARATION</param>
                <param name="value_column">NUMERO</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <timestamp name="version" column="DATE_VERSION"  unsaved-value="null" />

        <property name="dateDebutAdresseProvisoire" type="timestamp" column="DATE_DEBUT_ADRESSE_PROVISOIRE" />
....
    </class>
```

1st I have a table called SEQUENCE. This table stores the last ID of each object stored in. (some variable in French sorry : old code)

```
ENTITE         NUMERO   DATE   DISCRIMINANT
---------------------------------------
DECLARATION      2      NULL     NULL
....
```

When PK generator class is called, last ID is checked and incremented. If ID does not exist it creates one.

The PK generator class use IdentifierGenerator, Configurable interfaces.

```
public class PkGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

    public static final String ID_TABLE = "table";
    public static final String PK_COLUMN_NAME = "primary_key_column";
    public static final String PK_VALUE_NAME = "primary_key_value";
    public static final String VALUE_COLUMN_NAME = "value_column";
    public static final String PK_LENGTH_NAME = "primary_key_length";
    public static final Integer DEFAULT_PK_LENGTH = 64;

    // Valeurs par defaut
    public static final String DEFAULT_TABLE = "SEQUENCE";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PK_COLUMN = "SEQUENCE_NAME";
    private static final String DEFAULT_VALUE_COLUMN = "SEQUENCE_NEXT_VALUE";


// Membres
    private String tableName;
    private String pkColumnName;
    private String pkValueName;
    private String valueColumnName;
    private String query;
    private String insert;
    private String update;
    private int keySize;

...

@Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect) throws MappingException {
        this.tableName = params.getProperty(ID_TABLE, DEFAULT_TABLE);
        this.pkColumnName = params.getProperty(PK_COLUMN_NAME, DEFAULT_PK_COLUMN);
        this.pkValueName = params.getProperty(PK_VALUE_NAME);
        this.valueColumnName = params.getProperty(VALUE_COLUMN_NAME, DEFAULT_VALUE_COLUMN);
        this.keySize = ConfigurationHelper.getInt(PK_LENGTH_NAME, params, DEFAULT_PK_LENGTH);

        // select NUMERO from SEQUENCE with (updlock, rowlock) where ENTITE = '<TABLE>'
        this.query = "select " + this.valueColumnName + " from " + dialect.appendLockHint(LockOptions.UPGRADE, this.tableName) 
                   + " where " + this.pkColumnName + " = '" + this.pkValueName + "'" + dialect.getForUpdateString();
        // update SEQUENCE set NUMERO = ? where ENTITE = '<TABLE>'
        this.update = "update " + this.tableName + " set " + this.valueColumnName + " = ? "
                    + "where " + this.pkColumnName + " = '" + this.pkValueName + "'";
        // insert into SEQUENCE(ENTITE, NUMERO) values('keyValue', ?)
        this.insert = "insert into " + tableName + "(" + pkColumnName + ", " + valueColumnName + ") " 
                    + "values('" + "keyValue" + "', ?)";
    }

...

@Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {

/*      session.getTransactionCoordinator().getTransaction().createIsolationDelegate().delegateWork(
            new org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractWork() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    // do your work here, knowing you are in a new transaction
                    String tot = "";
                }
            }

            ,true
    );
    */

    Connection connection = session.connection();
    Integer pk = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection.prepareStatement(this.query);
        ResultSet resultSet = selectStatement.executeQuery();
        // Sequence exists
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            pk = resultSet.getInt("NUMERO");
        } else {
        // Sequence does not exist : create it (insert)
            pk = 0;
            PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement(this.insert);
            Boolean ok = insertStatement.execute();
        }

        // Sequence update
        pk = pk + 1;
        PreparedStatement updateStatement = connection.prepareStatement(this.update);
        updateStatement.setInt(1, pk.intValue());
        updateStatement.executeUpdate();
        String toto = "";

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new Integer(pk);
}
```

With the implementation of "Configurable" interface each instanciated generator will set members (table, name, column, ..) to get sequence value. Objects store also select, insert and update request in order to get last index, update it, create it if not exist.

***Now I'm just wondering if I execute select, update, insert in the generate methode of if I set another (isolated) transaction.*** and if I set a lock on database at select (before insert / update)